# How to validate decimal input not allowing alone "." and empty field?

Tags: java, android, validation, android-studio, escaping

I'm writing a calculator on Android Studio, in Java, and the app crashes if the user call the result with a dot "." alone or let the EditText field in blank.
I'm looking for a solution for not allowing these two conditions happening, together or individualy, in each of the three fields.
I've already tried TextWatcher and if/else but without success.

The .xml file where the editText field are designed is already set for decimalNumber.

I've already tried this:

```
if(myfieldhere.getText().toString().equals(".")){myfieldhere.setText("0");}
```

For each "valor line" and else for the "finalresult" line if everything is fine. Both inside the setOnClickListener block. This is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.peso_layout);
        result = findViewById(R.id.layresult);
        conc = findViewById(R.id.layconc);
        dose = findViewById(R.id.laydose);
        peso = findViewById(R.id.laypeso);
        calc = findViewById(R.id.laycalcpeso);

    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        float valor1 = Float.parseFloat(peso.getText().toString());
        float valor2 = Float.parseFloat(conc.getText().toString());
        float valor3 = Float.parseFloat(dose.getText().toString());
        float finalresult = valor1 * valor2 * valor3;
        result.setText("The result is: " + finalresult);
                }

    });
    }
```

The ideal output should be the app not crashing if these two conditions happen and sending an error message to the user that input is invalid.
What i'm receiving is the app crashing.
Thank you very much. I'm very beginner in Java and I'm few days struggling with this.

Comment: Exception is thrown from `Float.parseFloat`. You could catch it and display a `Toast` with an error message instead of computing result. That might be not what you want though.

Comment: Why don't you just get the text before the float and validating it? Eg if !empty, if != ".". Or opposite and return or whatever. Just simple validation... You seem to be overcomplicating it for little reason. You can also use try catch and just return.

Comment: M. Prokhorov, I can set the Toast but the app keep crashing, because it has no time to show the massage.
CmosBattery, I've tried this opposite, but I was getting error with the if statements.
Thank you both for the solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dear Friend, Your directly trying to convert string input into float and then after your check value but do your code like Below.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText edt1,edt2;
TextView txtans;
Button btnsum;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edt1=findViewById(R.id.edt1);
    edt2=findViewById(R.id.edt2);
    txtans=findViewById(R.id.txtans);
    btnsum=findViewById(R.id.btnsum);
    btnsum.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.btnsum){
        float n1,n2;
        String value1=edt1.getText().toString();
        String value2=edt2.getText().toString();

        if(value1.equals("") || value1.equals(".")){
            n1=0;
        }else {
            n1= Float.parseFloat(value1);
        }
        if(value2.equals("")|| value2.equals(".")){
            n2=0;
        }else{
            n2= Float.parseFloat(value2);
        }
        float ans=n1+n2;


        txtans.setText(ans+"");

    }
}
```

}

See In above code, F**irst  get value from edittext and then check wheather it contain null or "." inside it**. if it contains then store 0.0 value in some variable. then after make sum and display in textbox.

Comment: This solved the problem completely. Thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String myvalor = myfieldhere.getText().toString();
        if(myvalor.equals(".") || myvalor.isEmpty())
        {
            // toast error : incorrect value
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            float valor1 = Float.parseFloat(peso.getText().toString());
            float valor2 = Float.parseFloat(conc.getText().toString());
            float valor3 = Float.parseFloat(dose.getText().toString());
            float finalresult = valor1 * valor2 * valor3;
            result.setText("The result is: " + finalresult);
        }
        catch(Exception exp){// toast with exp.toString() as message}
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm having problems with boolean OR on my app, for some reason. 
The problem was already solved. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

use TextUtils for check empty String its better

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(peso.getText().toString())||
TextUtils.isEmpty(conc.getText().toString())||
TextUtils.isEmpty(dose.getText().toString())){
   return;
 }
```

Comment: For some reason the app doesnt allow OR boolean combinations in one line. Maybe I need to set it explicitly.
The problem was solved. Thank you very much for your answer.